# How to read Image tag src from rss-feed in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on getting rss-feed in Angular and I followed [this approach.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-rss-feed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I am able to read/get the data from my feed except for the image tag. My image tag looks like this

`<img width="150" height="84" src="https://simply-communicate.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/featured.png" alt="ice-dams" />`

How to get an src tag from enclosure media type.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want the image src from the string.

You can use regex to get the image src :

```js
let img = '<img width="150" height="84" src="https://simply-communicate.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/featured.png" alt="ice-dams" />';

let regex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)"/;
let src = regex.exec(img)[1];

console.log(src);
```

If you want to get the whole tag enclosure element :

```js
let enclosure = 'some string <enclosure url="https://cinfin.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/executive-with-client.jpg" length="68284" type="image/jpg" /> some other string';

let regex = /<enclosure(.*?)\/>/;
let src = regex.exec(enclosure)[0];

console.log(src);
```

Then if you want to get the list of all tags :

```js
let enclosures = 'some string <enclosure url="https://cinfin.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/executive-with-client.jpg" length="68284" type="image/jpg" /> some other string <enclosure url="https://cinfin.staging.wpengine2.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/executive-with-client.jpg" length="68284" type="image/jpg" />';

let regex = /<enclosure(.*?)\/>/g;
let all = enclosures.match(regex);

console.log(all);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you please tell me how to get the whole <img> tag from rss-feed instead of passing static url?

Comment: we are trying to to get the <enclosure> tag from here "https://cinfin.staging.wpengine.com/feed/" dynamically and pass to the img tag.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand

Comment: Sorry, some how the "<enclosure>" tag not showing on the feed url before. Now I added back https://cinfin.staging.wpengine.com/feed/ , could you please look in that.

Comment: i did not find any <enclosure> tag.

Comment: really, it look like this "<enclosure url="https://cinfin.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/executive-with-client.jpg" length="68284" type="image/jpg" />"

Comment: Check the updated answer you can now get list of them or the first one